# Use Bootstrap using appendChild

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap using vanilla javascript.

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="router.js"></script>
  <div id="my-app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**`router.js`**

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/register') {
    const myApp = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
    const layoutScript = document.createElement('script')
    const jQuery = document.createElement('script')
    const bootStrapJs = document.createElement('script')
    const jQueryCookie = document.createElement('script')

    const bootStrapMinCss = document.createElement('link')
    const bootStrapThemeCss = document.createElement('link')

    jQuery.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'

    bootStrapMinCss.type = 'text/css'
    bootStrapMinCss.rel = 'stylesheet'
    bootStrapMinCss.href = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'

    bootStrapThemeCss.type = 'text/css'
    bootStrapThemeCss.rel = 'stylesheet'
    bootStrapThemeCss.href = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'

    bootStrapJs.src = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'

    jQueryCookie.type = 'text/javascript'
    jQueryCookie.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js'

    layoutScript.type = 'text/javascript'
    layoutScript.src = 'javascripts/views/layout.js'

    myApp.appendChild(jQuery)
    myApp.appendChild(jQueryCookie)
    myApp.appendChild(bootStrapJs)
    myApp.appendChild(bootStrapMinCss)
    myApp.appendChild(bootStrapThemeCss)
    myApp.appendChild(layoutScript)
  }
})
```

The page loads just fine, and the styling is as I expect. However, I keep getting two errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

and

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`
```

When loading these script files directly into `index.html`, I get no errors.  However, I want to do this using JS.

Bootstrap requires jQuery, so I'm loading jQuery first, then all other assets, **so why does the browser think jQuery is not defined?**

Screenshot below:

[image]

**Update:**

By moving the jQuery import to my `index.html`, both errors go away.  So, `index.html` would look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="router.js"></script>
  <div id="my-app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is better, but still doesn't explain why I can't do the same thing in my router, using vanilla JS.

Comment: Did you include jquery library in the project

Comment: Yes.  `myApp.appendChild(jQuery)`.  That first line includes jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Change the constant name **jQuery** to anything else, because **jQuery** is a reserved keyword.

```
const load_jquery = document.createElement('script')
load_jquery.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'
myApp.appendChild(load_jquery)
```

Comment: That's a very good point, but I'm still getting the same two errors.

Comment: I've checked using chrome & firefox, I'm not getting this error after changed the constant name jQuery to load_jquery : http://prntscr.com/k459r7

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, since you are loading scripts dynamically they are not loaded in a synchronous way, ie the bootstrap script may get loaded before jquery is loaded.

You can try to load rest or the script in the load callback of jquery script

```
  jQuery.addEventListener('load', () => {
    myApp.appendChild(jQueryCookie)
    myApp.appendChild(bootStrapJs)
    myApp.appendChild(bootStrapMinCss)
    myApp.appendChild(bootStrapThemeCss)
    myApp.appendChild(layoutScript)
  });
  myApp.appendChild(jQuery)
```